# Adapter - microservice or dependency

Tags: java, microservices, soa

Suppose we have a core system based on Spring Boot (let's call it A), which now needs to be extended to communicate with another external service (let's call it B) via RESTful either asynchronously or synchronously by sending a JSON request with body containing XML file. 
Regarding to that, what is the best/most effective practice to solve it bearing in mind, that the whole architecture is being divided and developed to microservices? 
I see the 4 solutions: 
a) Service A sends requests to external application deployed as microservice which receives JSON body and translates it internally to request with XML body and then sends it to Service B 
b) Service A uses "Adapter or Connector" module which is an additional module besides the core application module and then, by using that module it translates all logic to JSON with body containing XML and then it connects to Service B 
c) Same as point b) but the exact request is being generated/built by the core application and the adapter just connects to the Service B without any parsing JSON body to XML body logic. 
d) An Adapter/Connector is a jar library added as an dependency to the core system, so that by importing, the core system just as in the point b)

Please, bear in mind that in the future, there will be a requirement to connect to Service B from another external application to use mostly the same API as Service A.
Hope it seems to be clear to you and I'll appreciate any advices.

Comment: Please clarify: which components are fixed (you won't change them), and which ones are you designing. Why "sending a JSON request with body containing XML file"? That is some weird way of doing things.

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel , the only component I can't change is the Service B. Right now I am designing the "Connector/Adapter" between the core Service A and Service B. Anyway, it's the API provided by Service B to accept requests with some headers and body which contains XML file.